# Does lowering the p-value threshold always result in lower FDR?

Tags: statistics, statistical-test

Intuitively I would think that lowering the o-value threshold would result in fewer false discoveries, but does this always hold or are there situations where it does not?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very interesting question, and I *think* that there may be situations in which reducing your p-value threshold *without good justification and attention to your design* does increase the false discovery **rate**, even though it would theoretically reduce the **number** of false discoveries across your tests. This is my guess based on the relationship between FDR and power.

This is my intuition because the FDCR is "false discoveries" divided by "true and false discoveries". So if you reduce the likelihood of true discoveries without *proportionately* reducing the likelihood of false discoveries, your FDR would increase. The way this relates to reducing the p-value threshold is that reducing the threshold without changing anything else would reduce your power. As the power of your test decreases, its ability to make true discoveries also decreases, and thus you might end up with a higher FDR. See [this paper](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rsos.140216) for a discussion of how the FDR, power and p-value relate.

This doesn't mean going for a higher p-value threshold btw, it means going for as stringent a threshold as would be appropriate and then increasing your power (increasing sample size, etc) until the power also is appropriate.